# Create new names for every unique variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am automating a pipeline and for this I need to make names out of every value that is in a list. for example:

```
data = structure(list(Line = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), Run = c("Run1", "Run2", 
"Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", 
"Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", 
"Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", 
"Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", 
"Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", "Run1", "Run2", 
"Run3", "Run4", "Run3", "Run4", "Run3", "Run4")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -48L))
```

what we can see is that for line 1, run 1 and 2 is present. for this I want to create a variable named "diff_Run1_Run2" for line 6 this would be "diff_Run3_Run4".

This example is straight forward. But it could be that a line is used with all 4 (Or more runs) which I would then want:

```
"diff_Run1_Run2"
"diff_Run1_Run3"
"diff_Run1_Run4"
"diff_Run2_Run3"
"diff_Run2_Run4"
"diff_Run3_Run4"
```

how can I approach this. In the future more Runs and more lines can be added, so I want to automate this process. How would you do this?

I tried:

```
list_for_automation <- list()


   for (i in unique(df$line)){
  values <- df%>% filter(line == i) %>% select(Run) %>% unique()
  
  list_for_automation <- append(list_for_automation, paste0("diff_",values[1,],"_", values[2,]))
  
}
```

But this will be a problem if a line has more runs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner approach (credit to @Onyambu):

```
data %>%
  reframe(all_combn=paste("diff",combn(unique(Run),2,\(x) paste(x,collapse="_")) ,sep="_"),.by=Line)

# A tibble: 11 × 2
    Line all_combn     
   <dbl> <chr>         
 1     1 diff_Run1_Run2
 2     1 diff_Run1_Run3
 3     1 diff_Run1_Run4
 4     1 diff_Run2_Run3
 5     1 diff_Run2_Run4
 6     1 diff_Run3_Run4
 7     2 diff_Run1_Run2
 8     3 diff_Run1_Run2
 9     4 diff_Run1_Run2
10     5 diff_Run1_Run2
11     6 diff_Run3_Run4
```

One `dplyr` approach with double `paste()`:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Line) %>%
  reframe(all_combn=paste("diff",combn(unique(Run),2) %>%apply(2,paste,collapse="_"),sep="_"))

# A tibble: 11 × 2
    Line all_combn     
   <dbl> <chr>         
 1     1 diff_Run1_Run2
 2     1 diff_Run1_Run3
 3     1 diff_Run1_Run4
 4     1 diff_Run2_Run3
 5     1 diff_Run2_Run4
 6     1 diff_Run3_Run4
 7     2 diff_Run1_Run2
 8     3 diff_Run1_Run2
 9     4 diff_Run1_Run2
10     5 diff_Run1_Run2
11     6 diff_Run3_Run4
```

Comment: Note that you do not need `apply`. Use the `FUN` parameter of `combn`. pass in the paste function accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

distinct(data) |> summarise(Run = paste0("diff_", paste0(Run, collapse = "_")), .by = Line)
```